# How to build a nav bar using *ngIf?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I am trying to dynamically build a nav bar in Angular 4 and understand Angular at the same time.

**app.components.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

export class newRoutes{
    route: string;
}
var NEWROUTES: newRoutes[]=[
    {route: "<li><a routerLink='/home'   routerLinkActive='active' [routerLinkActiveOptions]=' {exact: true}'>Home</a></li>"},
    {route: "<li><a routerLink='/scan'   routerLinkActive='active'>Order</a> </li>"},
    {route: "<li><a routerLink='/find'   routerLinkActive='active'>Search</a></li>"},
    {route: "<li><a routerLink='/status' routerLinkActive='active'>Status</a></li>"}
]
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Inspiredby';
    newroutes: newRoutes[] = NEWROUTES;
}
```

[image]**app.component.html**

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <p>{{title}}</p>
</div>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let newroute of newroutes">{{newroute.route}}</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Please see the image for the results.

I have tried putting the *ngFor in the `<ul>` and in a `<div>` between `<ul>` and the `</ul>` tags.

I thought that ngIf and ngFor were applied to the code before it is rendered. PS I have tried Googling it and there are some solutions but they don't fit the way I am working.

[image]

Comment: what is the question then? and where is the `*ngIf` you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

> your html should be like. you passing html so you need to bind html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <p>{{title}}</p>
</div>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let newroute of newroutes"><span [innerHtml]="{{newroute.route}}"></span></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

change array like

```
var NEWROUTES: newRoutes[]=[
    {route: "<li><a [routerLink]="['/home']"   routerLinkActive='active' [routerLinkActiveOptions]=' {exact: true}'>Home</a></li>"},
    {route: "<li><a [routerLink]="[/scan']"   routerLinkActive='active'>Order</a> </li>"},
    {route: "<li><a [routerLink]="['/find']"   routerLinkActive='active'>Search</a></li>"},
    {route: "<li><a [routerLink]="[/status']" routerLinkActive='active'>Status</a></li>"}
]
```

Comment: The nav bar displays now thank you but it does not work anymore. I believe it is because angular has stripped out some on my html. There is a warning Navigated to http://localhost:4200/
5platform-browser.es5.js:1017 WARNING: sanitizing HTML stripped some content (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss).